# loop in a module export javascript/sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have an index.js script that contains sequelize models

here is the tree structure of my folder

```
models/
   files/
   xml_files/
   csv_files/
   txt_files/
   index.js
server.js
```

this my `index.js` code :

```
const generate_files = require('./files')

const File = generate_files(sequelize, DataTypes)

const generate_xml_files = require('./xml_files')

const Xml_File = generate_xml_files(sequelize, DataTypes)

const generate_csv_files = require('./csv_files')

const Csv_File = generate_csv_files(sequelize, DataTypes)

const generate_txt_files = require('./txt_files')

const Txt_File = generate_txt_files(sequelize, DataTypes)

module.exports = {
 Files, Xml_File, Csv_File, Txt_File
}
```

in `` server.js ``` I imported each model like this :

```
const {Files, Xml_File, Csv_File, Txt_File} = require('./models')
```

Now in `server.js`  I want to get the name of the module sequelize then I check if the name of the module matches the name of the table like this :

```
const {Files, Xml_File, Csv_File, Txt_File} = require('./models')

if (Files.name == TableName){
  Files.findAll()
}

if (Xml_File.name == TableName){
  Xml_File.findAll()
}
if (Csv_File.name == TableName){
  Csv_File.findAll()
}
....
```

how can I avoid doing tests every time ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
const Example = require('./index')

Example.Files
```

As for making a loop, I'm not sure you can do that, but you can do:

```
export const File = generate_files(sequelize, DataTypes)
```

Which is the same thing as:

```
module.exports = {File}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so it's impossible to make a loop to get the name of the module?

Comment: I can't think of how to use a loop in any proper way, but even if you can you shouldn't, it'll just make your code confusing and less readable.  Using "export" before a declaration is really not a lot of effort and it makes the code easy to read and easy to see what's being exported just by quickly looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object and loop through the entries, like so.

```
var exports = {
  'File': './files',
  'Xml_File': './xml_files',
  'Csv_File': './csv_files',
  'Txt_File': './txt_files'
};

var e = {};
Object.entries(exports).forEach(ex=>{
  e[ex[0]] = require(ex[1])(sequelize, DataTypes);
});

module.exports = e;
```

Then you'll want to import them from this index file...

```
const {Files, Xml_File, Csv_File, Txt_File} = require('./models/index.js')
```

---

Per your update..

```
const Models = require('./models/index.js');
Object.entries(Models).forEach(model=>{
  if (model.name == TableName){
    model.findAll();
  }
}
```

Comment: indeed I want to get the name of the module sequelize in `server.js` then I check if the name of the module matches the name of the table

Comment: what? you're going to need to be much more clear than that. i have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: @Cissus - That really should have been in the question to begin with. I don't understand how you expected us to just know that. We're not mind readers. I've added that part to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your index.js you could also do it like this:

```
module.exports = {
    Files:    require('./files')(sequelize, DataTypes),
    Xml_File: require('./xml_files')(sequelize, DataTypes),
    Csv_File: require('./csv_files')(sequelize, DataTypes),
    Txt_File: require('./txt_files')(sequelize, DataTypes)
}
```

it's easier to read, at least for me.

Another way is to loop over the dir so you never need to change the code in index.js even if you add another folder like /xxx_files

```
const Fs = require('fs');

var dir = Fs.readdirSync(__dirname, { withFileTypes: true });

var exports = {};

dir.forEach(d => {
    if (d.isDirectory())
        exports[d.name] = require('./' + d)(sequelize, DataTypes);
});
// !!!!!!! the names of the exports will be names of the directories 
module.exports = exports;
```

And to avoid the checks `if (Files.name == TableName)`
all you need is to **not** import like this:

```
const {Files, Xml_File, Csv_File, Txt_File} = require('./models')
```

but rather like this:

```
const models = require('./models')
// models = { files, xml_files, csv_files, txt_files }
```

then you can do this:

```
var db = models[TableName] // assuming TableName is files, xml_files etc.
if (db)
    doSomething();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer indeed File.name allows to access the name of the table of the model and for my part the name of the model is different from the name of the table for example 
 ``` 
const Files = sequelize.define(
    file_report',
....
return Files
}
 ``` 
so when I do Files.name I must have as return value file_report

Comment: Well you could name the exports by the sequelize model name, instead of `exports[d.name] = require('./' + d)(sequelize, DataTypes)` do this `var model = require('./' + d)(sequelize, DataTypes)` and then `exports[model.name] = model`